# How to filter out substring in one python pandas data frame by comparing with result of another dataframe separated by different characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can i filter rows in a dataframe by comparing another dataframe .
My dataset consists of two columns Col1 and Col2 .Here Tricky part is that values in lookup Col2 are seperated by '-' ,however  Col1 is seperated by underscore "_" .
I am trying to filter out substring in col1 by comparing with result of another dataframe column .

```
I have following dataset. 
--------------------------------------------------
Col1                   Col2        COL3 (Desired Output)                                                                                                                         
|---------------|----------------|---------------|
| One_Two_Three | Two-Three      | One           |
| Four_Five_Six | Five-Six       | Four          |
| Seven_Eight_Ni| Eight-Ni       | Seven         |
```

Tried to write below code but unable desired output .

```
df[col3]=df.apply(lambda x: x['col1'].replace(x['col2'], "").strip(),axis=1)
```

With above line of code ,i am just able replace first substring (i.e getting _Six in last row) .

Also unable to remove extra underscore in the desired outputs.

Any help would be highly appreciable .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [`rsrtip('_')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) and [`lstrip('_')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html) which will remove leading and trailing underscores to your code:

EDIT: You can add an extra `.replace('-','_')` on your Col2 to replace `-` with `_`.

```
df['Col3'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['Col1'].replace((x['Col2'].replace('-','_')), '').rstrip('_').lstrip('_'), axis=1)
```

Prints:

```
>>> df 
             Col1       Col2   Col3
0   One_Two_Three  Two-Three    One
1   Four_Five_Six   Five-Six   Four
2  Seven_Eight_Ni   Eight-Ni  Seven
```

This will give you your desired result

Comment: Thanks  @sophocles  !                                                                                                       **| col1          | col2           | Desired OutPut|**
| --------      | -------------- |               |
| One_Two_Three | Two_Three      | One           |
| Four_Five_Six | Six            | Four_Five     |
| Seven_Eight_Ni| Eight_Ni       | Seven         |
| Eleven_Six    | Eleven         | Six           |

Comment: I just realised that some of my datasets are different . In Col2 , values are seperated by '-' ,however  Col1 is seperated by underscore "_" . 
Col1                   Col2        COL3 (Desired Output)                                                                                                                         
| --------      | -------------- |               |
| One_Two_Three | Two-Three      | One           |
| Four_Five_Six | Five-Six       | Four          |
| Seven_Eight_Ni| Eight-Ni       | Seven         |
Could you please help me to achieve above desired output .

Comment: Can you please update your question? So that I can work on getting you your desired outcome?

Comment: Thanks @sophocles  . I have just edited the problem statement .

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks @sophocles !

Answer (score 0):

You can first break the string to list and use a set operation to find the remaining parts before joining them back.

```
df.apply(lambda x: '_'.join(set(x.Col1.split('_')) - set(x.Col2.split('_'))), axis=1)

0          One
1    Four_Five
2    Ten_Seven
3          Six
```